# Xquery Split a string by the Nth occurrence of a character

Tags: xquery

I need some help with splitting a long string of characters by the Nth occurrence of a certain character. For example

```
<string>1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27</string>
```

to be split by the 9th comma 
and to become

```
<string>1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9</string>
<string>10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18</string>
<string>19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27</string>
```

The length of the original string is not specified and the numbers 1-27 in the example could be words with spaces, but the comma is uniquely a separator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
let $s := <string>1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27</string>
let $len := 9
let $tokens := tokenize($s, ',')
for $n in (1 to count($tokens) idiv $len)
return <string>{ 
  string-join(subsequence($tokens, $len * ($n - 1) + 1, $len), ',') 
}</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

For further reference, here is another solution using XQuery 3.0. It does not use regular expression, but instead a [tumbling window](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-tumbling-windows).

```
let $s := '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27'
for tumbling window $w in tokenize($s, ',')
    start at $start when true()
    end at $end when $end - $start eq 8
return <string>{$w}</string>
```

This looks like the model use case for windows, in my opinion. It is quite nicely readable: Use a tumbling window (in contrast to a sliding window, which slides only one element further in the sequence each turn, a tumbling window never overlaps) and start at the beginning of the sequence. End a window if there are 9 elements in the window (i.e. 8 in between the start and the end).

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to XQuery 3.0, you can also use `analyze-string(...)` using some regex foo:

```
let $string := '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27'
let $result := analyze-string($string, '(?:[^,]+,){8}[^,]+')
return $result/fn:match
```

Please realize the number of recurrences in the regular expression is one less as the number of values you want to partition after; it resembles the number of values together with commata, and a single value afterwards.

If you also have to deal with the tail, eg. when dividing the string into tuples of 8 numbers:

```
let $string := '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27'
let $result := analyze-string($string, '(?:[^,]+,){7}[^,]+')
return $result/(fn:match/string(), *[last()]/substring(., 2))
```